# Mongodb grouby by and sum and get media

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this collection in my database:

```
{ "IdUser" : "1", "IdItem" : "1" },
{ "IdUser" : "1", "IdItem" : "2" },
{ "IdUser" : "1", "IdItem" : "3" },
{ "IdUser" : "2", "IdItem" : "4" },
{ "IdUser" : "2", "IdItem" : "5" },
{ "IdUser" : "4", "IdItem" : "6" },
{ "IdUser" : "5", "IdItem" : "7" }
```

How can I obtain this result:

> Users with one item: 2
>
> Users with two items: 1
>
> Users with three items: 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the **[`aggregate(`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate)**) method will give you the desired result though the output documents would be different in that instead of having a key/value pair, you have two different fields with values that show the number of users and their respective
item count. The following aggregation pipeline explains this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$IdUser",
            "count": { 
                "$sum": { "$cond": [{ "$gt": [ "$IdItem", null ] }, 1, 0 ] } 
            }            
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$count",
            "users": { "$push": "$_id" }            
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0, 
            "number_of_items": "$_id", 
            "number_of_users": { "$size": "$users" } 
        }
    }
])
```

In the above, you **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** all the documents by the user key to get their counts, taking into consideration documents that may not have the item field, which would be discounted in the aggregate. A further **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** operation is necessary to then get the users per count, in the form of an array.

The last step in the pipeline **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** serves to reshape the final output so that you get the following output (with the sample documents supplied with the question):

```
{ "number_of_items" : 1, "number_of_users" : 2 }
{ "number_of_items" : 3, "number_of_users" : 1 }
{ "number_of_items" : 2, "number_of_users" : 1 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to first [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) your documents by `IdUser` then count the number of time each `IdUser` appear in your collection using the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) accumulator operator. This allows you in the next stage to group your documents by "count" and return the count for "user" with same number of "items".

```js
db.items.aggregate([
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$IdUser", 
        "count": { "$sum": 1 } 
    }}, 
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$count", 
        "nUsers": { "$sum": 1 } 
    }}
])
```